# Section tag not moving

Tags: html, css

My section tag inside of my section tag which has an id of mainBody is not being pushed down, it is supposed to be 20 pixels downwards from the top of the mainBody.
Code:
Index.html: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1361141/
reset.css and main.css: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1362043/

Comment: I agree with Kyle. I actually skipped your question because i coulnt be bothered to read it all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more about the collapsing margins here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing in case you prefer MDN documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Its called margin-collapsing and is normal behaviour.
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Simply remove the margin (top and bottom) on the .news element.
and add:

```
padding: 20px 0 ;
```

on the #mainBody

Furthermore, you are not using the Section element correctly #mainBody should almost certainly be a div.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, could you tell me why I am not using the Section element correctly please? I would like to know why it should be a div rather than a section element.

Comment: The section element represents a generic document or application section…The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead.